# Connection Pooling in Nodejs (Using sequelize)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, connection-pooling

I write the code below. According to my understanding the **"max:"** in pool shows the max number of connection we can create in pool. So if I set the value of **max as 0**. Then it should not established any connection. I just want to clarify this.

```js
var sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD, {
        pool:{
                 max: 0,
                 min: 0,
                 idle: 10000,
                 acquire:30000
             },
        logging: console.log("connection created"),
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        operatorsAliases: false
    }
);
```

Comment: should create an issue on the ```sequalize``` repo on and ask the maintainers of the repo directly

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Sequelize but simply we can create a connection this way.I think this will be little bit helpful for you.

```
   /**
 * create connection pool
 */
var con = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100000,
    host: 'enter host',
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME
});

con.getConnection(async function(err, connection) {
    let result=connection.query('SELECT * FROM table_name');
    console.log(result);
    if(err) throw err;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with the way they have it set up in their examples exactly?

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.uri, {
  pool: {
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000,
  },
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: config.db.ssl,
  },
  // logging: logger.debug.bind(logger),
});
```

the models utilize it on their own... what am i missing here?

Comment: This is not an answer, you should have asked in comment section

Answer (score 0):

For `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`, you can't set `pool.max` to `0` anymore. If you do this, `sequelize` will throw an error:

> max must be an integer > 0